# How do I check for a role in a specific server?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, roles

Here is my code:

```js
client.on('message', message => {
    if (message.content === '+sdrive') {
        if (message.channel.type === "dm") {
            if (message.member.roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Nitro Booster')) {
            }
        }
    }
})
```

I need it so that it will check if the person has a role in a specific server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this command is sent via DM, you need to tell the Bot which guild it should check. 
I'm not sure if there is a shorter version, but this should do the trick:

```js
if (client.guilds.cache.get("YOUR_GUILD_ID").members.cache.get(message.author.id).roles.cache.some(role => role.name === 'Nitro Booster')){
    // Do something...
}
```

**Note:** The User and the Bot have to be on the same server!

---

Less noisy version:

```js
const hasRole = client.guilds.cache
    .get("YOUR_GUILD_ID").members.cache
    .get(message.author.id).roles.cache
    .some(role => role.name === 'Nitro Booster');

if (hasRole){
    // Do something...
}
```